# Keep image stationary, that's location is relative to nearby text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the very middle of the screen I have a piece of text, along with an image. When the text gets longer, the image is forced to move the right, which is what its supposed to do. But what I want it to do, is keep the image in the same spot, and make the text shift over to the left instead.

(I will also be adding more names so I need this fix to be universal, not like manually changing it for each piece of text.)

(It might be hard to see, but its noticeable, and yes I'm using a template...)

[image: Image one]

[image: Image two]

[My site - Updated link](http://panjaco.com/test/)

I tried messing with the HTML to get the margin-right once the page is fully loaded, then when it updates the text change the margin-right to that, but it did absolutely nothing.

Any help is appreciated, I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: Hey buddy! Your site looks nice, but it would be much better if you can create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the relevant code to help us solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, I will work on that right now.

Comment: Ok i updated the link, to a minimal version of it.

Comment: try using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of inline block elements, that might help

Comment: I went into the main.css and mine, and changed inline-block to inline flex- and block to flex, and mixed them together but it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
#banner .content {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 1%;
        max-width: 95%;
        padding: 6em;
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: middle;
        z-index: 1;
        float: left;
        width: 66%;
}
```

Comment: I just put that in my stylesheet, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'm adding this two styles: float: left; width: 66%; live on your site, and it works great. Maybe try to clear cookies?

Comment: I'm using a local version of it, so I don't have to do that. one second

Comment: The image is still moving though

Comment: So just remove float: left; and add text-align: left; to #banner. Works here :D.

Comment: My pleasure :).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by defining the `width` property for the containing `content` layer, and then floating the image and the text to the right.

For example, if you want the right-hand side of the text to be aligned to the center of the page your image + it's left-hand margin needs to be half the width of the containing `#banner .content` layer.

With your image being `18rem` square with a left-margin of `3rem` your containing `#banner .content` div needs to be `42rem` wide ((18 + 3) * 2).

```
#banner .content {
    position: relative;

    width: 42rem;
    height: 18rem;

    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;

    /* center div.content */
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    display: block;

    z-index: 1;
}

#banner .content .image {
    width: 18em;
    height: 18em;

    border-radius: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

    margin-left: 3rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Content inside `.content` slides to the right with the `span.image` locked to its right-hand edge.  As long as the text-container's width (`header`) does not exceed half the width of `.content' it will remain right-aligned 3rem from images left-hand side.  Avoid using css-padding for positioning control and use css-margin properties instead.